# Call stored procedure within update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am merging a table and calculating new values in the updated output table. Is it possible to execute a stored procedure with params from the merging table within the update statement? Something like this, a simplified example:

```
MERGE db1.Table1 db1Table
USING (SELECT [Column1], [Column2]
       FROM db2.Table1) AS org ON db1Table.TableID = org.TableID

WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
        SET [Column1] = org.[Column1],
            [Column2] = org.[Column2],
            [Column3] = (EXEC myProcedure @Param1 = org.[Column1]  
                                          @Param2 = org.[Column2])
```

Comment: No but you can do this with a scalar user defined function. It's not advised though - there are usually performance issues. It might be easier to precalc the right value in the USING part though

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You can use the output clause to capture details about the modified rows and loop through them calling the SP afterwards.

Comment: My approach would be:

1) Create a table valued function (TVF) doing the calculation if complex only
2) Create a view over db2.Table1 joining the potential TVF
3) Use this view to act as merge source

Main benefits are easier to debug and change and separation of complexity over cost of multiple objects. WITH SCHEMABINDING in the view helps preventing unintended breaks.

Comment: Also please see https://sqlblog.org/merge

Comment: The return value of a procedure is generally used to return a "status" indication of success / fail, not actual data. Don't take the path of using that return value in a manner that is completely difference and inconsistent with general tsql development practices.

Comment: If you are using transact SQL language then you cannot execute a query which is not in transact SQL language unless you change the language, and the format which you present does not fit T-SQL. It sound like a "XY problem". If we would know what is your exact needs and not what is your solution/idea then we might find a different approach. For example, **Instead of "Call stored procedure within update statement", why can't you "Call update statement within stored procedure"?**

Comment: The reason being I am adding logic to already existing merge statement but as you point out this needs a better consideration. I am actually considering a different approach at the moment. Thanks for your help.